# Python3.6 and Pyautogui - Pixel commands - TypeError: __new__() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, python-3.6, pyautogui

I'm relatively new to Python and I'm attempting to make a fun little project using **Pyautogui** and **Python3.6**. The goal of this project is to create a tensorflow powered project that learns to play chess. The problem I am now encountering is that whenever I try to use any of the **pixel** commands - e.g. pyautogui.pixel(...) or screenshot.getpixel(...) - an error pops up and says this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 109, in <module>
    Score()
  File "main.py", line 100, in Score
    if gui.pixelMatchesColor(tempX, tempY, (87, 83, 82), tolerance=20):
  File "/Users/student/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 413, in pixelMatchesColor
    pix = pixel(x, y)
  File "/Users/student/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 436, in pixel
    return RGB(*screenshot().getpixel((x, y)))
TypeError: __new__() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

I just want to note that all other commands work fine and that it's only the **pixel** ones that don't work.

I have installed everything including pyautogui(duh), pyscreeze, pymsgbox, pytweening, xlib, opencv, and any other package I could think of. These were installed using this command: **pip3 install** *package-name-here* **--user**. I needed the **--user** because I don't currently have administrator rights to my computer so I'm wondering if that could have something to do with my current predicament.

I also encountered an earlier post in my search for an answer but I forgot where I found it, so I'm sorry but I can't link it, but basically it said that I should go through and remove all **pycache** folders. I did this using the terminal command in the ~/Library/Python/3.6 folder:

```
find . -name "__pycache__" -type f -o -name "__pycache__" -type d -exec rm -rf {} \
```

I am in no need of an exact solution to this problem, but I'm wondering if there's some way to use the pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(...) function **or any similar one that you recommend** that can have a tolerance - e.g. that the RGB values can be 10 units off and still return **true**.

For those of you that are interested, here is my full code:

```
#
# IMPORT ALL NECESSARY THINGS
#

import os, time, sys, pyautogui as gui, argparse as arg

#
# FAILSAFES
#

gui.FAILSAFE = True
gui.PAUSE = 0.1

#
# SET UP ARGUMENT PARSER
#

parser = arg.ArgumentParser(description='A machine learning script powered by TensorFlow designed to be run on "chess.com" using Python.')
parser.add_argument("-s", "--sleep", nargs='?', type=int, default='5', help='Number of seconds that the program should sleep before starting. This gives you time to move over to the website before the program looks for the gamboard on screen.')
args = parser.parse_args()

#
# ASKS USER FOR WHAT SIDE IT IS ON
#

side = input("Are you white or black?  ")

if side == "W" or side == "w" or side == "white" or side == "White":
     side = "W"
elif side == "B" or side == "b" or side == "black" or side == "Black":
    side = "B"
else:
    print("Invalid selection for which side!")
    side = None
    sys.exit(0)

#
# PRINT "READY" AND THEN WAIT FOR SPECIFIED AMOUNT OF TIME - DEFAULT 5 SECONDS
#

print("Ready! Waiting for " + str(args.sleep) + " seconds!")
time.sleep(int(args.sleep))

#
# GET AREA OF GAMEBOARD ON SCREEN
#

if side == "W":
    gameboard = gui.locateOnScreen('./img/white/chessboard_white.png', confidence=0.55, grayscale=True)
    left = gameboard.left - 10
    top = gameboard.top - 5
    right = gameboard.left + gameboard.width + 10
    bottom = gameboard.top + gameboard.height + 15
elif side == "B":
    gameboard = gui.locateOnScreen('./img/black/chessboard_black.png', confidence=0.55, grayscale=True)
    left = gameboard.left - 10
    top = gameboard.top - 5
    right = gameboard.left + gameboard.width + 10
    bottom = gameboard.top + gameboard.height + 15

widthInterval = (right - gameboard.left) / 8
heightInterval = (bottom - gameboard.top) / 8

#
# DEFINES A FUNCTION THAT COUNTS THE SCORE 
# - NUMBER OF YOU SIDE AND THEN SUBTRACT THE NUMBER OF OPPOSITE SIDE
#

def Score():
    for i in range(8):
        for j in range(8):
            tempX = 32 + (i * widthInterval)
            tempY = 32 + (j * heightInterval)
            if gui.pixelMatchesColor(tempX, tempY, (87, 83, 82), tolerance=20):
                print("True!")
    
    if side == "W":
        print("White!")
    elif side == "B":
        print("Black!")


Score()
```

Note: The problem occurs in the last 10ish lines of the above code.

Thank you so much for your help and please don't hesitate to let me know if you need any more info from me!
Max

Comment: Having this error too, it has to do with pyscreeze failing to get pixels